# Run a Postgresql command inside docker

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

How to run a Postgresql command inside a docker container?
i tried using this line:

```
docker-compose run db psql pfe
```

But i get and error:

```
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
Is the server running locally and accepting
connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Comment: map the docker address:port to host system while running. `docker-compose run db psql pfe -p 5432:5432`

Comment: It's ok thanks, i found the solution, and i anwsered the question already. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I need to run the command in the working container so thats why i need to use docker-compose exec instead of docker-compose run. Also i need to mention the user by adding -U flag to the command:

```
docker-compose exec db psql pfe -U admin

db:    the containser name
pfe:   the database name
admin: the database user
```

WORKING VERRY FINE!